# Haskell "fix" keyword failed on declaring a recursive lambda function

Tags: haskell, recursion, lambda, fixpoint-combinators

Seems a function should have a name to be recursive(in order to call itself), so how does a lambda function be recursive?

I searched wikipedia and it says this could be done by a "Y-combinator". I don't have much math theory backgroup, it just tell me that "Y-combinator" is discovered by Haskell himself. Called "fix" keyword in Haskell language, I tried:

```
Prelude> let fact = fix (\f n -> if n == 0 then 1 else n * (f (n-1)))

<interactive>:17:12: Not in scope: ‘fix’
```

Seems failed, but how to use "fix" keyword to do what I expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fix` is defined as:

```
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f = let x = f x in x
```

so it expands into `f (f (f (f ...)))` i.e. an infinite sequence of nested applications of the input function `f` to some parameter `x`.

You can give your lambda function a top-level definition e.g.

```
factF f n = if n == 0 then 1 else n * f (n - 1)
```

or equivalently:

```
factF :: (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int)
factF f = \n -> if n == 0 then 1 else n * f (n - 1)
```

you can provide this function to `fix` to obtain a function `(Int -> Int)` i.e.

```
fact :: (Int -> Int)
fact = fix factF
```

if you expand this definition you get

```
factF (factF (factF (factF ...)))
=> \n -> if n == 0 then 1 else (factF (factF (factF ...)))
```

due to laziness, the repeated applications of `factF` are only evaluated if `n /= 0` so the above function applied to `0` will evaluate immediately to 1.

You can see in this expansion that `factF` is being provided as an argument to itself which it then applies to smaller version of `n`. Since `factN` is the same as your lambda function, the same thing is happening there - the parameter `f` inside the lambda is the lambda itself which it can then call recursively.

Answer (score 12):

`fix` is not a keyword, it is a function defined in the `Data.Function` module. Therefore, to use it, you must import that module.

```
import Data.Function
```

or in GHCi:

```
:m Data.Function
```